# How to redirect customer to a correct URL after migrated wordpress to nopCommere

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, http-status-code-301, nopcommerce

We have migrated our website from wordpress to nopcommerce. Now our all old customer are trying to open product page using old url **www.domain.com/product/{product-url}** which is wordpress supported one

But nopCommerce having structure like **www.domain.com/{product-url}**

Is there anyway to redirect to new url with correct product page?

Thanks,
Jatin

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to make new URLs works.
1). Add rewrite rule to web.config file, which simply check the requested URL format, if it contains `/product/` then it will be redirected to product slug.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>        
        <rule name="rewritewithfallback">
          <match url="(.*)product/(.*)$" />          
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:2}"  redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  ......
 ......

</system.webServer>
```

2). Add rewrite rule for one common action method, code to redirect to the product action by code.

*Note: Check with incognito window, otherwise you will have unexpected behavior of redirect just because of cashing.*

Hope this helps!